# how to split a string in field data MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

In locale for an example(id-id)

I want update query for this locale

How I need to split the string hyphen should change to underscore, last 2 digits should be upper case

o/p should be: id_ID

I've been tried this query

```
UPDATE  substring_index(locale,'-',1)=substring_index(locale,'-',1),
locale=REPLACE(locale,'-','_'),
substring_index(locale,'-',-1)=UPPER(substring_index(locale,'-',-1))
jlg_language_code_mapping;
```

Please help me guys..!

[image]

Comment: you should be asking a question related to MySQL DB, but not Oracle which has no function `substring_index()` but MySQL has. So, I'm removing Oracle from the title and tagging area.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan at least i've been tried in MySQL but expecting the answer in oracle bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, locale) as
  2    (select 'arabic', 'ar'                  from dual union all
  3     select 'indonesian', 'id-id'           from dual union all
  4     select 'malay', 'ms-my'                from dual union all
  5     select 'bulgarian', 'bg'               from dual union all
  6     select 'chinese (simplified)', 'zh-cn' from dual
  7    )
  8  select id, locale,
  9    regexp_substr(locale, '^\w+') ||
 10    replace(upper(regexp_substr(locale, '-\w+$')), '-', '_') new_locale
 11  from test;

ID                   LOCALE                    NEW_LOCALE
-------------------- ------------------------- -------------------------
arabic               ar                        ar
indonesian           id-id                     id_ID
malay                ms-my                     ms_MY
bulgarian            bg                        bg
chinese (simplified) zh-cn                     zh_CN

SQL>
```

Update:

```
update your_table set
  locale = regexp_substr(locale, '^\w+') ||
           replace(upper(regexp_substr(locale, '-\w+$')), '-', '_');
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. but I want update query which I have done above. can you make changes?

Comment: Sure, I just did. Have a look.

Comment: It's updating only a single word for an example(id), it should be updated as id_ID, you can see above image instead hyphen(-), should be underscored (_), last two alpha should be upper case.

Comment: Sorry, had to go offline. Sorry #2, forgot about replacing hyphen with an underscore - fixed now. But, as of lower to upper case, it worked as you said ... at least, that's what my example shows, isn't it?